# Fullscreen modal, shows the first picture, need to show the picture clicked instead of the first one

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I have a problem, been at this for a long time and just can't get it to work, guy's help me out here.

I have an 'AngularJS', 'HTML webapp', the app fetches the posts from an 'FB page' though 'OpenGraph', the data comes in 'JSON' format, and displays the images in cards, with pictures and text, that the user can scroll down through the cards, currently 10 cards are displayed, everything is working just fine, except one thing, when the user clicks the image on the card, it alway's opens the first image, from there the user can scroll through the images left and right.

What i need is that when the user clicks a photo, it's that photo being shown, not the first one. Please help! :)

The 'JSON' data returns a 'data array', so i have 10 sets of data.

This is the function that loads the photo in the modal, and is set to '0', so it always shows the first picture:

```
  $scope.openModal = function() {
  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
  $scope.modal.show();
  };
```

How can i change that, so the picture will correspond to the picture clicked?

If someone wants to see a working demo, leave you e-mail, i'll send you an invite to view the app within 'Ionic View'.

## Here's the complete code below:

```js
angular.module('mattymode.controllers', ['ionic'])


.controller('FB_Ctrl', function($scope,$http) {

function makeHttpRequest() {

try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
catch (error) {}

try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
catch (error) {}

try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
catch (error) {}

throw new Error ("HTTP Request Could not be completed.");
}


var appID = "appID";
var appSecret = "appSecret";

var accessTokenRq = makeHttpRequest();
var httpString = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+appID+'&client_secret='+appSecret;

accessTokenRq.open("GET",httpString,true);
accessTokenRq.send(null);

var access_token;

accessTokenRq.onreadystatechange = function() {

  if (accessTokenRq.readyState == 4) {

    access_token = accessTokenRq.responseText;
    //alert("It works!");

    var request = makeHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET",'https://graph.facebook.com/fbpageid/posts?'+access_token+'&fields=id,message,picture,link,name,description,type,icon,likes,comments,created_time,from,object_id&limit=10)',true);
    request.send(null);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (request.readyState == 4) {

        var response = request.responseText;
        console.log(response);

        var fbData = angular.fromJson(response);

        var data = fbData.data;

        var messageArray = [];
        var pictureArray = [];
        var likeArray = [];
        var dateArray = [];
        var linkArray = [];
        var typeArray = [];
        var commentArray = [];

        var objects = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          
          var entry = data[i];

          // Message
          if (entry.message) {
             var message = entry.message;
             messageArray.push(message);
          }
          else {messageArray.push(" ");}

          // Picture
          if(angular.equals(entry.type,"photo")) {
            var pic = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+entry.object_id+"/picture?type=normal";
            pictureArray.push(pic);
          }
          else if (angular.equals(entry.type,"link")) {
            pictureArray.push(entry.picture);
          }
          else {pictureArray.push("empty");}
          //console.log(pic);
            
          // Likes
          if (entry.likes) {
            var likeData = entry.likes;
            likeArray.push(likeData.data.length+" Likes");
          }
          else {likeArray.push(" Likes");}

            
          // Date 
          var created = entry.created_time;
          var rawDate = created.split("T");
          var date = rawDate[0];

          var rawTime = rawDate[1];
          var time = rawTime.split(":");
          var betaTime = time[0]+":"+time[1];
          var finalTime = addOneHour(betaTime);
          dateArray.push(date+" - "+finalTime);

            function addOneHour(time) {
              var seperatedTime = time.split(":");
              var hourTime = seperatedTime[0];
              var returningTime = "";
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("00") > -1) {returningTime = "01";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("01") > -1) {returningTime = "02";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("02") > -1) {returningTime = "03";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("03") > -1) {returningTime = "04";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("04") > -1) {returningTime = "05";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("05") > -1) {returningTime = "06";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("06") > -1) {returningTime = "07";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("07") > -1) {returningTime = "08";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("08") > -1) {returningTime = "09";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("09") > -1) {returningTime = "10";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("10") > -1) {returningTime = "11";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("11") > -1) {returningTime = "12";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("12") > -1) {returningTime = "13";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("13") > -1) {returningTime = "14";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("14") > -1) {returningTime = "15";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("15") > -1) {returningTime = "16";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("16") > -1) {returningTime = "17";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("17") > -1) {returningTime = "18";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("18") > -1) {returningTime = "19";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("19") > -1) {returningTime = "20";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("20") > -1) {returningTime = "21";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("21") > -1) {returningTime = "22";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("22") > -1) {returningTime = "23";}
              if (seperatedTime.indexOf("23") > -1) {returningTime = "00";}

                console.log(returningTime+":"+seperatedTime[1]);

              return returningTime+":"+seperatedTime[1];  

              }

          // Link
          if (entry.link) {linkArray.push("empty");}
          else {linkArray.push("empty");}

          // Comments 
          if (entry.comments) {
            var commentData = entry.comments;
            commentArray.push(commentData.data.length+" Comments");

          }
          else {
            commentArray.push("0 Comments");
          }


          typeArray.push(entry.type);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++) {
          
          // Only Text 
          if ( (angular.equals(linkArray[i],"empty")) && (angular.equals(pictureArray[i],"empty")) ) {
            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button">Bekijk</a> </div>');
          
          }

          // No Link, picture availiable
          else if ( (angular.equals(linkArray[i],"empty")) && (angular.equals(pictureArray[i],"empty")) == false ) {
            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><img src="'+pictureArray[i]+'" width=100%></img> <p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button">Bekijk</a> </div>');

          }

          // The rest 
          else {
            objects.push('<div class="list card"><div class="item thumbnail-left"> <h2>Matty Mode</h2><p>'+dateArray[i]+'</p></div><div class="item item-body"><a href='+linkArray[i]+' ><img src="'+pictureArray[i]+'" width=100%></img></a> <p>'+messageArray[i]+'</p><p><span class="subdued">'+likeArray[i]+'</span>  <span class="subdued">'+commentArray[i]+'</span></p></div> <a class="button-block button">Bekijk</a> </div>');

          }

        }

        $scope.entries = objects;
        $scope.pictures = pictureArray;
      }
    }
  }

}


})

.controller('IMG_Ctrl', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', '$ionicSlideBoxDelegate', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
    
   $scope.aImages = [{
       'src' : $scope.pictures[0], 
       'msg' : ''
     }, {
        'src' : $scope.pictures[1], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[2], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[3], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[4], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, {
        'src' : $scope.pictures[5], 
       'msg' : ''
     }, {
        'src' : $scope.pictures[6], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[7], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[8], 
        'msg' : ''
        }, { 
        'src' : $scope.pictures[9], 
        'msg' : ''
    }];
    
    //console.log($scope.pictures);
  
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('image-modal.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    $scope.openModal = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
      $scope.modal.show();
    };

    $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $scope.modal.remove();
    });
    // Execute action on hide modal
    $scope.$on('modal.hide', function() {
      // Execute action
    });
    // Execute action on remove modal
    $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
      // Execute action
    });
    $scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
      console.log('Modal is shown!');
    });

    // Call this functions if you need to manually control the slides
    $scope.next = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    };
  
    $scope.previous = function() {
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.previous();
    };
  
   $scope.goToSlide = function(index) {
      $scope.modal.show();
      $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
    };
  
    // Called each time the slide changes
    $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {
      $scope.slideIndex = index;
    };
  }
])

.controller('FAQ_Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [];

  $scope.groups = [
  { name: 'Hoe werkt deze app?', id: 1, items: ['Met deze app kunt u onze hipste en meeste betaalbare mode bekijken op uw mobiel of tablet. Elke week zullen er meerdere outfits beschikbaar zijn, daar wij iedere weekeen nieuwe collecite in de winkel hebben, waarvan de meeste slechts voor een korte periode beschikbaar zijn.']},
  { name: 'Reserveren', id: 2, items: ['Ja, dat kan, u kunt ons bellen of whatsappen op nummer 06-28656008, wat u het fijnst vindt, let wel, wij hangen de bestelling voor maximaal 3 dagen apart, daarna gaat het terug bij de collectie.']},
  { name: 'Retourneren', id: 3, items: ['U kunt artiekelen binnen 1 week ruilen, op vertoon van de bijbehorende kassabon, mits deze niet gedragen en/of gewassen zijn, en enkel als de kaartjes nog aan de kleding vastzitten. LET WEL: Wij geven geen geld terug, u ontvangt van ons een tegoedbon, voor het aankoopsbedrag.']},
  { name: 'We geven geen garantie', id: 4, items: ['Strasssteentjes', 'Kwastjes', 'Kettingen', 'Emblemen', 'Loslatende naalden of stikkels', 'Verkeerde wasvoorschriften/gebruik']},
  ];
  
  /*
   * if given group is the selected group, deselect it
   * else, select the given group
   */
  $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };
  
});
```

```css
/* Fullscreen image */
.transparent {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.image-modal {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}
.fullscreen-image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 55px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* Fix modal backdrop for smaller devices */
@media (max-width: 679px) {
  .active .modal-backdrop-bg {
    opacity: .5;
  }
  .modal-backdrop-bg {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Accordion lists */
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}

/*
 * http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#usage_animations
 */
.list .item.item-accordion {
  line-height: 38px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  transition: 0.09s all linear;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0px;
}
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-add,
.list .item.item-accordion.ng-hide-remove {
  display: block !important;
}

.item.wrap, .item-content.wrap {
white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Outfits" style="background-color:#333333">
  <ion-content class="padding">
      <p style="text-align:center"><img src="img/mm_icon.png"></p>
      
    <div class="list" >
        <div ng-repeat = "entry in entries track by $index" ng-bind-html="entry" ng-click="openModal()" ng-controller="IMG_Ctrl">

            <script id="image-modal.html" type="text/ng-template"> 
              <div class="modal image-modal transparent" ng-click="closeModal()"> 
                  <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" show-pager="false"> 
                      <ion-slide ng-repeat="oImage in aImages"> 
                          <img ng-src="{{oImage.src}}" class="fullscreen-image" /> 
                          <p class="info">{{oImage.msg}}</p> 
                      </ion-slide> 
                  </ion-slide-box> 
              </div> 
            </script>

        </div>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a parameter to your `openModal()` function from the view. Something like this:

**View**

```
<div class="modal image-modal transparent" ng-click="closeModal($index)">
```

Then handle the param on your openModal function like this:

**Controller**

```
$scope.openModal = function(index) {
  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
  $scope.modal.show();
 };
```